# how to build perf tools with riscv64-linux-musl-x86_64?

Tags: performance, linux-kernel, embedded-linux, perf, musl

build perf tools in linux_5.10 kernel

make CROSS_COMPILE=riscv64-unknown-linux-musl- ARCH=riscv64

Makefile.config:417: *** No gnu/libc-version.h found, please install glibc-dev[el].  Stop.
Makefile.perf:232: recipe for target 'sub-make' failed
make[1]: *** [sub-make] Error 2
Makefile:69: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2

Comment: with NO_LIBELF =1 can success, but i need this feature.

Answer (score 1):

```
diff --git a/tools/perf/Makefile.config b/tools/perf/Makefile.config
index ce8516e4d..f263ed544 100644
--- a/tools/perf/Makefile.config
+++ b/tools/perf/Makefile.config
@@ -388,6 +388,7 @@ else
     ifeq ($(BIONIC),1)
       LIBC_SUPPORT := 1
     endif
+    LIBC_SUPPORT := 1
     ifeq ($(LIBC_SUPPORT),1)
       msg := $(warning No libelf found. Disables 'probe' tool, jvmti and BPF support in 'perf record'. Please install libelf-dev, libelf-devel or elfutils-libelf-devel);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).